# Resize TextFile (Keep X amount of first lines and delete the rest of lines)

Tags: .net, vb.net, text, text-files, lines

I'm trying to delete all the lines after "X" number of line in a textfile, I mean to keep the first "X" amount of lines and delete the rest of lines.

I know how to do this by this way:

```
1. Open the textfile
2. Read line by line
3. Count the line number.
4. Store the line content and append the string in the new textfile
5. Continue reading the next line and doing the same (step 3 & 4).
6. When line-count reaches "X" then stop reading lines.
```

Too much steps and slow method to do this, someone know a better improved (fast) way to keep the first 1.000 lines of a textfile and delete the rest lines?

```
Private Sub Resize_LogFile()
    If File.ReadAllLines(LogFile).Length > 1000 Then
        ' Delete all the lines after line number: 1.000
        ' Save it
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: How big is your file (KB, MB, GB)?

Comment: Do you want to keep the first X lines or remove the last X lines?

Comment: @Steve less than 1 mb, this time the size of the file will be around 300-500 kb, but I'm looking for the fast way to use it with bigger files.

Comment: Your definition of X lines is confusing. Your bottom sample code says you are keeping the first X lines (ie: 1000 lines, and remove whatever no of lines present after that)

Comment: @ajakblackgoat You are right, sorry, what I really need is to keep the first "X" amount of lines, I will make the corrections in my question thanks. PS: Sorry for my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below codes work for me:

```
    Using fs As New FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open)
        Dim pos As Long = 0

        Using sr As New StreamReader(fs)
            For i As Integer = 1 To maxNumOfLines
                Dim line As String = sr.ReadLine()
                pos += line.Length + 2
            Next

            fs.SetLength(pos - 2)
        End Using
    End Using
```

Comment: But be aware, in your case, you are truncating Log file. So you might want to keep the last X lines, because, the lines are appended overtime to the bottom of the file. So the most recent log activities are at the bottom of the file right?

Comment: OMG I don't know how I don't noticed that, really my log file is only logging URL's, but you are right the most recent urls are appended to the bottom of the textfile, so I think in two solutions: 1st: append the urls at the start of the textfile, or 2nd: keep the last x lines like you said, can you help me with that editing your answer please?

Comment: In that case, you need to change the question or better, ask another question. Since this question and answer perhaps are useful to others and better kept as reference.

Comment: No matter, I found a solution to reverse the textfile first and then manipulate the lines, thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to edit the file in place first read through X lines to find out where the end of the Xth line in then truncate the file at that position. This solution never has more then one line of the file referenced so will not take any more memory for larger files. However it will take more time for larger files.

```
Using fs As New FileStream(Logfile, FileMode.Open)
    Using sr As New StreamReader(fs)
        For i As Integer = 1 To X
            sr.ReadLine() 'Read X lines
        Next
    End Using
    fs.SetLength(fs.Position) 'Remove all following text
End Using
```

If however you want to use a new file then your algorithm is the best there is due to the unpredictability of where the line endings are.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it says "overload resolution failed because no "New" accepts this number of arguments", can you tell me which is the correct option I need to use for the second argument in the new Filestrem? (FileMode.Create?)

Comment: Also the "fs.SetLength(fs.Position)" line says: Can't get acces to a closed file."

Comment: @ElektroHacker Sorry forgot the file mode, corrected, for the second error check the  fs.setlength  is between the two usings

Answer (score 0):

Found this and did a little modifications I think is a better (fastest) solution:

No "For" needed so no hangs in the app, I'm happy :)

```
Private Sub Resize_LogFile()
    Dim MaxLogEntries As Int32 = 1000
    Dim MinLogEntries As Int32 = 500
    If File.ReadAllLines(LogFile).Length > MaxLogEntries Then

        Dim strArray() As String = File.ReadAllLines(LogFile)
        Array.Reverse(strArray)
        ReDim Preserve strArray(MinLogEntries)
        Array.Reverse(strArray)
        Using WriteLogFile As New IO.StreamWriter(LogFile, False, Encoding.Default) : WriteLogFile.WriteLine(String.Join(vbNewLine, strArray)) : End Using

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: how does array.reverse work without a loop? There are at least four iterations of the file in this method

Comment: This should be slower than your original solution as your reading in the whole file twice. Then looping over the file at least three times and storing at least twice the length of the file in memory